# How to replace Unit Separator in for xml auto query

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I want to replace all the xml unit separator in all the columns in a table.

This is my query:

```
SELECT *    
FROM [TableName] as t    
FOR XML auto, TYPE
```

So far, everything is great, but once I parse the XML, I got an error because apprently one of my rows got a unit separator in it.

Is there a way to replace the unit separator directly in the query?

Comment: Show us what a *XML unit separator* looks like - can you show us a sample of your XML that causes problems?

Comment: the Xml unit separator that i got is &#x1F ,here is a sample of my xml  :<firstName>Alex</firstName><clientNo>437885</clientNo><email>Alex_&#x1F; @marc_s

Comment: @SKGeek did the response answered the question, if so, please mark it as answered.

Comment: @LuisLL No it did not answer my question , i tried ur approach but i still got the same error

Comment: so what's the status now? did you manage to solve? if you didn't manage, please add the full details of the error message, if you manage to solve, please share with the community your solution. Thanks

Comment: @LuisLL I still didn't manage to solve it , and here is the full Exeception Message that i get : Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML' in test.php:24

Comment: @SKGeek how do you know that only offending value? what do you see if you execute `SELECT * FROM [TableName]` from SSMS? do you see any other offending character?

Comment: @LuisLL the thing is I don't see any offendinG Character at all , it only show while parsing the Xml.

Comment: @SKGeek probably because the character is low ASCII x1F which will not show in standard output. what happens if you try the changed SQL in SSMS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need the unit separator? Can't you remove them from the predicate?

```
SELECT ClientNo, REPLACE(email,`&#x1F;`,``) as email, [other columns... ]
FROM [TableName] as t    
FOR XML auto, TYPE
```

edited change:

```
; with t as (
    SELECT ClientNo, REPLACE(email,`&#x1F;`,``) as email, [other columns... ]
    FROM [TableName] 
) 
SELECT * 
FROM t
FOR XML auto, TYPE
```

Comment: For me giving '&#x1F;' as an argument does not work (with LIKE or REPLACE). But it works with CHAR(31). So do REPLACE(...,CHAR(31),...) or LIKE '%'+CHAR(31)+'%'